# Getting Bash error too many arguments while running bash script

Tags: linux, bash, hdfs

I am trying to write some logic based avro files available in a directory

But I am getting too many arguments error .

```
 [cloudera@client01 scripts]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-06

Found 11 items
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera          0 2017-04-24 13:57 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/_SUCCESS
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera     781714 2017-04-24 13:56 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part-r-00000-7e1d4e4e-9166-4744-b73b-095a7cc0e090.avro
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera     782132 2017-04-24 13:56 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part-r-00001-7e1d4e4e-9166-4744-b73b-095a7cc0e090.avro
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera     782467 2017-04-24 13:56 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part-r-00002-7e1d4e4e-9166-4744-b73b-095a7cc0e090.avro
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera     785117 2017-04-24 13:56 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part-r-00003-7e1d4e4e-9166-4744-b73b-095a7cc0e090.avro
```

When I apply the below if condition I get below error.

```
[cloudera@client01 scripts]$ if [ hdfs dfs -test -e "/user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-06/part*.avro" ];
> then
> echo "PASS"
>  else
> echo "FAIL"
>  fi
-bash: [: too many arguments
FAIL


[cloudera@client01 scripts]$ if [ hdfs dfs -test -e /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-06/part*.avro ]; then   echo "PASS";  else echo "FAIL";  fi
-bash: [: too many arguments
 FAIL
[cloudera@client01 scripts]$
```

I dont know what went wrong in my if condition .
Could someone help me to fix this error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code should be :

```
if
  hdfs dfs -test -e "/user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-06/part*.avro"
then
  echo "PASS"
else
  echo "FAIL"
fi
```

Note the removal of the `[]`.

The condition in an `if` statement is a command, and it will be considered "true" if its return code is 0, and "false" otherwise.

The `test` command (often used in its `[ ]` form) is a command that performs tests on its arguments and returns a true/false value.  The tests it performs do not inclure executing its inner content as a command.  I suggest you look it up, it is very useful.

However, if you just need to test the success/failure of a command, you do not need it, just use the command itself as the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know that your script ran successfully, try the following:

```
hdfs dfs -test -e "/user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-06/part*.avro" && echo "PASS" || echo "FAIL"
```

Or you could just check the return status with `echo $?`.
If this is zero, the last bash command was a success, anything else is a failure (this would be the return status from the last command your script executed up to the point that you check `$?` which includes **ANY** bash command such as `echo`).  Often, you'll find that the `man` page for whatever command you're running (or the POSIX `man` page) will provide more information on the exact error code.

Comment: Yes. Your suggestion worked.. brackets make sense.. Thanks!

Comment: @Fred you are quite correct, not sure what I was trying there! - removed second part